# {{value}} — view displays old value

Tags: angular7

After changing field value in source the view still displays old value. 
Angular engine is using 'strict equality'(===) for change detection?

How to solve this problem (I don't like the solution below)? Thx

```
SOURCE:
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    date: Date = new Date();

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    change() {
        this.date.setHours(11);                   // not working

        //const newDate = new Date();     
        //newDate.setHours(11);
        //this.date = newDate;                    // working
    }
}
```

**Template  VIEW:**

```
<div>
  <button (click)="change()">
    Change
  </button>
  <h4>
    {{date}}
  </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try ng-click…
I think you need to do two way data binding in this scenario...

Comment: check out official example https://angular.io/guide/user-input, it should work. I do not need two way binding - the date value is changed in source.

Answer (score 0):

@BitVer try this, you are changing the `Date` object but it's not two way binding that's why it's not updated in template view.

But you can change the `date` variable by reassigning to it again.

```
 change() {
   this.date = this.date.setHours(11); 
 }
```

Comment: date.seHours  - Return Value: A Number, representing the number of milliseconds between the date object and midnight January 1 1970, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp.                 Of course with `this.date = new Date(this.date.setHours(11));`  It works, but that is the same solution like before.